# REST API How to get result with date > YYYY-mm-dd instead of date = YYYY-mm-dd

Tags: api, rest, datetime

I'm trying to prepare request from REST API system which is administrated by government, so I have to use provided API methods without possibility to change it from server side.
The URL of this GET method is ...​/WasteRegister​/WasteTransferCard​/v1​/Kpo​/sendercards​/receiver
One of parameters is called "ReceiveConfirmationTime": string($date-time).
Because of limits (2 queries per second, max 50 records per page) and lots of records from previous years, I would like to get records only from current year. When I prepare request i.e. ​/WasteRegister​/WasteTransferCard​/v1​/Kpo​/sendercards​/receiver?ReceiveConfirmationTime=2023-01-18 it gives me results only from this specific day and it's correct. Unfortunately there is no parameter such a "Year" which would be solution for me.

So what I've tried so far:

- limit value from this request to only year ReceiveConfirmationTime=2023 - it gives an error with incorrectly date-time formatted value and it's obvious
- operator > instead of = it gives a result with all records including previous years

I've tested it in PHP (curl), Postman and online API test pages - all without success.
So, my question is: is there any way for preparing this request URL i.e. use operator a'la like in SQL? I will be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: In general: if the server's resource model doesn't include the resource that you want, there's not anything you can do to change that.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I found another parameter which is called: cardNumber and it have result values i.e.: 00004/2023/KPO/0003/000032733, so we have a part of value "/2023/KPO" which defines a year of wastecard. Unfortunately this kind of filtering is very time consuming, so it works only with smaller data stores (small number of all rows in table). When I change to another data store an error is thrown. Probably it's timeout issue. So unfortunately I'm stuck...